# XML to XML using XSLT php

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to transfrom xml file to another using php through xslt.
On the output I need some adjustments, but I don't know how to adjust my xsl stylesheet.

Thanks for your help

Needed adjustments on the output:

- add dynamic counting to category element like `<category1> <category2>`...
- add all content of element SIZE of PRODUCT/COLORS/COLOR/AVAILABLE_SIZE to `<$color>` element like `<green>S:M:L:XL</green> <orange>L:M</orange>`
- add dynamic counting to image element like `<image1> <image2>`

source xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PRODUCTS>
 <PRODUCT>
  <CODE>19</CODE>
  <NAME>daisy</NAME>
  <MANUFACTURER>79</MANUFACTURER>
  <DESCRIPTION>t-shirt</DESCRIPTION>
  <SIZES></SIZES>
  <PRICE>33.33</PRICE>
  <PRICE_AKCIA>24.17</PRICE_AKCIA>
  <CATEGORY_ID>42</CATEGORY_ID>
  <CATEGORIES>
    <CATEGORY>clothes</CATEGORY>
    <CATEGORY>t-shirt</CATEGORY>
    <CATEGORY>latest</CATEGORY>
  </CATEGORIES>
  <COLORS>
   <COLOR>
    <NAME>green</NAME>
    <IMAGE>http://www.xyz.com/userfiles/daisy_green.png</IMAGE>
    <AVAILABLE_SIZES>
     <SIZE>S</SIZE>
     <SIZE>M</SIZE>
    </AVAILABLE_SIZES>
    <SIZES>
     <SIZE>S</SIZE>
     <SIZE>M</SIZE>
     <SIZE>L</SIZE>
     <SIZE>XL</SIZE>
    </SIZES>
   </COLOR>
   <COLOR>
    <NAME>orange</NAME>
    <IMAGE>http://www.xyz.com/userfiles/daisy_orange.png</IMAGE>
    <AVAILABLE_SIZES>
     <SIZE>L</SIZE>
     <SIZE>M</SIZE>
    </AVAILABLE_SIZES>
    <SIZES>
     <SIZE>S</SIZE>
     <SIZE>M</SIZE>
     <SIZE>L</SIZE>
     <SIZE>XL</SIZE>
    </SIZES>
   </COLOR>
  </COLORS>
 </PRODUCT>
</PRODUCTS>
```

xsl stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="products">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="PRODUCTS/PRODUCT"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PRODUCTS/PRODUCT"> 
    <xsl:element name="product">
        <xsl:element name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="CODE"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="NAME"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="model">
            <xsl:value-of select="CODE"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="manufacturer">
            <xsl:value-of select="MANUFACTURER"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="category_id">
            <xsl:value-of select="CATEGORY_ID"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="CATEGORIES"/>
        <xsl:element name="description">
            <xsl:value-of select="DESCRIPTION"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="price">
            <xsl:value-of select="PRICE"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:element name="special">
            <xsl:value-of select="PRICE_AKCIA"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="COLORS/COLOR"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="COLORS"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CATEGORIES">
    <xsl:for-each select="CATEGORY">    
      <xsl:element name="category">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="COLORS">
    <xsl:for-each select="COLOR/NAME">    
      <xsl:variable name="color" select="." />
      <xsl:element name="{$color}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="COLOR/AVAILABLE_SIZES"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="COLORS/COLOR">
    <xsl:for-each select="IMAGE">    
      <xsl:element name="image">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="COLOR/AVAILABLE_SIZES">
    <xsl:for-each select="SIZE">    
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>:
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
  <product>
    <id>19</id>
    <name>daisy</name>
    <model>19</model>
    <manufacturer>79</manufacturer>
    <category_id>42</category_id>
    <category>clothes</category>
    <category>t-shirt</category>
    <category>latest</category>
    <description>t-shirt</description>
    <price>33.33</price>
    <special>24.17</special>
    <image>http://www.xyz.com/userfiles/daisy_green.png</image>
    <image>http://www.xyz.com/userfiles/daisy_orange.png</image>
    <green/>
    <orange/>
  </product>
</products>
```

Comment: Hello! Could you add your expected output too, as that would make it even clearer what you require? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have dynamically named elements, you can make use of Attribute Value Templates to specify the element name.

So, if you wanted **category1**, **category2**, etc, instead of just **category** you would do this

```
 <xsl:element name="category{position()}">
```

The curly braces indicate this is an expression to be evalulated.

However, if you were to do this directly with your code for images, you would see they would all be suffixed by 1.

```
<xsl:template match="COLORS/COLOR">
    <xsl:for-each select="IMAGE">    
      <xsl:element name="image{position()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

This is because you are getting the position of the **IMAGE** element within the **COLOR** element. Really you want the position of the parent **COLOR** element. Instead, it might be better to match the **COLORS** element here, then you could get the position of the **COLOR** element.

```
<xsl:template match="COLORS">
    <xsl:for-each select="COLOR">    
      <xsl:element name="image{position()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="IMAGE"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Of course, this means you end up with two templates matching **COLORS** so you probably want to combine them. However, there is a problem with the other template. You are iterating over **COLOR/NAME**, which means you will be positioned on a **NAME** element within the loop. Therefore when you try to select **COLOR/AVAILABLE_SIZES** it is looking for them below the current element, where they don't exist. You should probably be doing this

```
<xsl:template match="COLORS">
    <xsl:for-each select="COLOR">    
      <xsl:variable name="color" select="NAME" />
      <xsl:element name="{$color}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="AVAILABLE_SIZES"/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <!-- Code to do images from above -->
</xsl:template>
```

A couple of other things to note. You only really need to use **xsl:element** if you want dynamic element names (like shown above), otherwise just output the element directly.

Also, in many cases, all you are doing is converting an upper-case name to lower case. It might be simpler to have a generic template for this

```
<xsl:template match="*">
   <xsl:element name="{translate(
         local-name(), 
         'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
         'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')}">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
     </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

This would cut down on the code you would need to write. You would only need specific templates when you wanted to change element names to something totally different.

Try the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="*">
      <xsl:element name="{translate(local-name(), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')}">
         <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </xsl:element>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="CODE">
      <id>
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </id>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="PRICE_AKCIA">
      <special>
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </special>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="CATEGORIES">
      <xsl:for-each select="CATEGORY">
         <xsl:element name="category{position()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
         </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="COLORS">
      <xsl:for-each select="COLOR">
         <xsl:variable name="color" select="NAME"/>
         <xsl:element name="{$color}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="AVAILABLE_SIZES"/>
         </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:for-each select="COLOR">
         <xsl:element name="image{position()}">
            <xsl:value-of select="IMAGE"/>
         </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="AVAILABLE_SIZES">
      <xsl:for-each select="SIZE">
         <xsl:if test="position() > 1">:</xsl:if>
         <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output

```
<products>
   <product>
      <id>19</id>
      <name>daisy</name>
      <manufacturer>79</manufacturer>
      <description>t-shirt</description>
      <sizes/>
      <price>33.33</price>
      <special>24.17</special>
      <category_id>42</category_id>
      <category1>clothes</category1>
      <category2>t-shirt</category2>
      <category3>latest</category3>
      <green>S:M</green>
      <orange>L:M</orange>
      <image1>http://www.xyz.com/userfiles/daisy_green.png</image1>
      <image2>http://www.xyz.com/userfiles/daisy_orange.png</image2>
   </product>
</products>
```

Comment: please, one more thing, if the name of color has two words e.g. light blue, elements have to be named light_blue, because error while transforming. Pls, How to avoid this?

Comment: This is straight-forward, using the 'translate' function to replace a space with an underscore. It is probably best to ask a whole new question, if you can't work it out straight-away, as this question is already fairly large. Thanks!